# How can I use awk for modify a column based in the first column?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a data like this, and I need automatize a simple task. I need to make the second value of a row, become the same as the first cell in the next row in the sequence like this:

```
First Second
1   2
4   6
10  12
25  28
30  35
```

Become

```
First Second
1   4
4   10
10  25
25  30
30  35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==1; NR>2{print p[1], $1} {split($0,p)} END{print p[1], p[2]}' file
First Second
1 4
4 10
10 25
25 30
30 35
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted your output is wrong, you cannot know the `35` because that row has not been read yet:

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 {print $1} {printf $1 "\t"}' file
1       4
4       10
10      25
25      30
30
```

Comment: Never do `printf $1` or similar using input data in the format field of a printf statement, always do `printf "%s", $1` instead. Imagine the difference when `$1` contains printf formatting characters like `%s`.